# RDP constantly dropping

Tags: remote-desktop

I connect from the office to the house over RDP.  I used to not have an issue with this configuration, but over the past 4-5 months it's steadily dropped connections.  Seems every 5 seconds or so the "Trying to reconnect" dialog pops up, it reconnects, it works for a few seconds, then "freezes" again until the "Trying to reconnect" dialog appears again.

It's quite annoying.

I thought it might be the router, so I replaced it with a new one.  This seemed to make the problem go away for a week or two, but now the problem is back.

The frustrating part is I don't know how to diagnose where this is being cut off.  Is it being dropped by work's proxy server, is it something at home?

Can anyone suggest how I might go forward with figuring this out?

Comment: @Grant - you're right on both counts.  Sorry bout that.  Do I just ask the question over there or is there a way to move it?

Comment: You can click the flag button under your post and flag if as off topic for migration.  A moderator can then move it for you.

Comment: This is more likely a VPN problem than an RDP issue I would guess.  Are you using VPN or is this an RDP over Web services via some internet based portal?

Comment: no, it's straight rdp to an uncommon port.  RDP enabled on home pc, port changed, router set to port-forward requests on that port from my work pc.